# Extracting up to three numbers from string in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in pandas which can contain one to three numbers in string format which I need to extract first and then sum up. The numbers are separated by commas and can be floats indicated by a dot.

The second issue is that the floats contain more decimal places than necessary.

```
df['Numbers'] = ['0, 0, 15', '0', '456.2345, 0, 23.1543', '512']
```

Integers should simply be extracted the way they are.

Floats should have the following format "\d+\.\d\d" (limited to two decimal places but not rounded up or down).

The ideal output would look something like this:

```
df['number1'] = [0, 0, 456.23, 512]
df['number2'] = [0, NaN, 0, NaN]
df['number3'] = [15, NaN, 23.15, NaN]
```

Comment: Maybe using regex matches like `r"[^,;]+"` and then using `Float` on them could help.

Comment: again to extract only the two decimals after the dot you can use a regex match like this: 
`r"([0-9]{,}\.[0-9]{2})"`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I have found that works for me is to split at the ', ' into a new dataframe. Then transform it to numeric, sum it up and merge the column back to the old dataframe.

```
df_2 = df['Numbers'].str.split(', ', expand=True)

df_2[0] = pd.to_numeric(df_2[0], errors='coerce')
df_2[1] = pd.to_numeric(df_2[1], errors='coerce')
df_2[2] = pd.to_numeric(df_2[2], errors='coerce')

df_2['Value'] = df_2[0] + df_2[1] + df_2[2]

df = df.merge(df_2['Value'], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```